# MVC2: Non-view aspx page in iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, http-status-code-404, asp.net, telerik-reporting

I have a contradiction to deal with:

I need  to make a stylesheet load for a reporting object (for ASP.NET  -- it requires runat), however, it won't compile when I have <% %> tags in . I need the <% %> stuff in  to load stylesheets and jscripts for the rest of the page.

So, I'm going to load the reporting object into an  wrapped in a non-view, non-master-bound aspx page -- so I don't need the other CSS stuff (it's in the Site.Master outside of the iframe)... however, I'm getting a 404 when I load /APP/Reports/viewer.aspx... so it seems to be a controller thing.

I tried googling for the answer, but I'm not sure how to ask the question.

Comment: I think some colleagues of mine had a similar type issue with reporting (SSRS). I think the only way they got that to work was to have a normal aspx within the MVC app.